Assertion failing when trying to assert an ID number in a URL Path
I am trying to do the following:
Assert the URL path after being redirected.
Here is an example of the Url: https://www.hello.com/test/test-result?testId=100
cy.location("pathname").should("eq", "/test/test-result"
cy.location("search").should("eq","/\?testId=\/\d+/)

The first assertion passes, but the second one fails.
The error I get is the following:  expected ?testId=100 to equal /?testId=/\d+/
Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? I thought using d+ would be good since it will match any number.

Your link is broken.

What's wrong is you are not using regex matching correctly. An example of the syntax is Cypress "have.attr" with regular expressions

I think you should change the pattern matching ?testId=100 as follows:
cy.location("search").should("match", /\?testId=\d+/)

cy.location("search") should return the string: ?testId=100, 
which can be match against regex /\?testId=\d+/.
